# Timevis - use custom css to change font size

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

I would like to produce a timevis plot in which the font size changes based on the importance of the variable.

Using the 'style' option in the source data frame, I am able to change the font colour. However, when I use this same method to try to change the font size, R doesn't render the variables correctly.

Here is a sample of my data:

```
data <-    structure(list(groups = c("Deadline.1", "Deadline.1", "Deadline.1", 
"Deadline.1", "Deadline.1"), content = c("Geography Tutorials: Critical 
Thinking & Techniques",  "Principles of Geographical Inquiry I", "Geography 
in Action", 
"Physical Geography: Earth Surface Processes & Landforms", "Biogeography & 
Ecology"
), start = structure(c(17459, 17505, 17631, 17911, 18048), class = "Date"), 
end = structure(c(17459, 17505, 17631, 17911, 18048), class = "Date"), 
type = c("point", "point", "point", "point", "point"), id = c(1L, 
2L, 7L, 9L, 10L), Assessment = c("1500 word essay ", "Group survey", 
"20% attendance (5% per block)", "2 hr exam ", "2 hr exam "
), Percentage = c(15, 15, 20, 100, 100), style = c("'font-size:15px;'", 
"'font-size:15px;'", "'font-size:20px;'", "'font-size:100px;'", 
"'font-size:100px;'")), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is the relevant piece of my code. Obviously in the final version, I will make a more subtle link function between 'percentage' and font size. But this doesn't work regardless of font size.

```
library(shiny)
library(timevis)
library(tidyr)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)


data$style            <- paste0("'font-size:", data$Percentage, "px;'")


### example time vis rendering (doesn't work)

timevis(data = data[2:3, ])  ### random variable choice


### but this works

data$style            <- 'color: red'
timevis(data = data[2:3, ])
```

Any suggestions are very welcome. I am a modeller not an app developer primarily, so apologies if this is due to a trivial HTML error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the `'` and it will work:

```
data$style <- paste0("font-size:", data$Percentage, "px;")
timevis(data = data[2:3, ])
```

[image]